# Calculating XIRR from XIRR of multiple portfolios

Tags: stocks, investing, mutual-funds

I have two portfolios of mutual funds, each showing its respective XIRR. I would wish to know the XIRR of my all portfolios to evaluate how every portfolio or investment strategy is working. Is it possible to do that without entering data manually in excel for every transaction of both portfolios and then finding XIRR? if yes, then how?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could get a *rough* estimate by weighting the respective IRRs. Depending on the makeup and turnover of each portfolio, you can weight each portfolio by initial balance or average balance. If you want the *exact* IRR of the combined portfolios you'll have to get the cash flows of each portfolio separately. A weighted average IRR is just an estimate, and there are no formulas to aggregate IRRs.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helps :)